# Laravel OneAuth session issue

Tags: php, facebook, session, twitter, laravel

I have installed the OneAuth bundle for social integration on Laravel PHP and have ran into an issue. I can authorize the Facebook and Twitter applications through a call to

```
mysite.dev/connect/session/twitter
mysite.dev/connect/session/facebook
```

and I'm redirected back to the correct url to handle the callback request. I try to retrieve the session data using:

```
Session::get('oneauth');
```

This session is always null. I have spend a lot of time on this looking for possible reconfiguration but have came up empty handed. Any ideas?

Additional information:

The oneauth_clients database row is also not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Session::get('oneauth');
```

you must follow how methods are called

Comment: My apologies, that's what I already have. (Switched to c# last night after this project, so still in C# mode)

Comment: This is very confusing! How did you have the problem if you were just in the wrong mindset? Rico's code matches yours in the question.